# Cast interface{} to a type

Tags: go

Say I have something like this:

```
type Foo struct{
   Bar string
}

func Exported (v interface{}){
 // cast v to Foo
}
```

is there a way to cast v to Foo in the Exported func?

I tried a type assertion like so:

```
func Exported (v interface{}){

  v, ok := v.(Foo)

  if !ok {
    log.Fatal("oh fuk")
  }

  // but v.Bar is not available here tho ??

}
```

The problem is that if I try to access v.Bar after the assertion, it doesn't compile.

Comment: Go doesn't support casting at all. Only type conversions.

Comment: If you read the compilation error, it will tell you why it doesn't work, and should provide sufficient information to find a working solution.

Comment: I'm not aware of any strictly typed language where the behavior you describe would work. Are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func main() {
    f := Foo{"test"}
    Exported(f)
}

type Foo struct{
    Bar string
}

func Exported (v interface{}){
    t, ok := v.(Foo)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("boom")
    }
    fmt.Println(t.Bar)
}
```

Comment: see my answer, there is a way to avoid have to do any more work - you have to continue to cast v to Foo  even after the assertion, my way you don't have to.

Comment: You're lucky I am cool, you got it, appreciate all upvotes ty

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the variable name `v`. Please refer below code

```
func Exported (v interface{}){

  v, ok := v.(Foo)

  if !ok {
    log.Fatal("oh fuk")
  }

  // but v.Bar is not available here tho ??

}
```

here, interface name is `v` and after typecasting, it is assigning to variable `v`
Since `v` is `interface` type, you are not able to retrieve value of `Foo` struct.

To overcome this problem, use another name in typecasting like

```
b, ok := v.(Foo)
```

And you will be able to get `Bar` value using `b.Bar`

The working example is below:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    foo := Foo{Bar: "Test@123"}
    Exported(foo)
}


type Foo struct{
    Bar string
}

func Exported (v interface{}){
    // cast v to Foo
    b, ok := v.(Foo)

    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("oh fuk")
    }

    fmt.Println(b.Bar)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I was making this mistake:**

```
func Exported (v interface{}){

  v, ok := v.(Foo)

  if !ok {
    log.Fatal("oh fuk")
  }

  // but v.Bar is not available here tho ??

}
```

you need to use a different variable name:

```
func Exported (x interface{}){

  v, ok := x.(Foo)

  if !ok {
    log.Fatal("oh fuk")
  }

  // now v.Bar compiles without any further work

}
```